# how to avoid top layer overlap label of baselayer in geoserver?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, sld

I have a problem with map using Geoserver and OpenLayers 2

I have a base layer is polygon with label. I have a river layer overlap base layer. 
 How can I make label of polygon layer not showing (or display on top river layer) when being overlap by river layer?

this is image of map
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7HWF.png

Answer (score 0):

If instead of requesting the two layers separately which doesn't allow GeoServer to know about the labels in the other layer, you requested both layers together then GeoServer can manage the label layout for you and you will not see any overlaps.

Comment: That's wonderful, Iant! I following you, add 2 layer to one group in geoserver and that work perfectly, all labels of polygon were on top of river layer. But there is any way to "requested both layers together" because I want each layer is show in layer tree, maybe turn on/off layer in map?